AWS EKS cluster access created using cdk by a federated SAML user
I am creating an AWS eks cluster using AWS cdk using the a federated SAML user.
I have tried  adding a kubernetes manifest to update the aws-auth configmap within the eks stack cdk code but no success so far.
Once the eks cluster gets created, neither I have access to eksctl or kubectl (the kube config context is updated correctly and also I am using the correct aws profile when trying to use eksctl and kubectl)
When I login into aws console, the federated user show up like this -> <role-name>/<user-name>
aws sts get-caller-identity outputs UserId as XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:<user-name> and Arn as arn:aws:sts::<account-id>:assumed-role/<role-name>/<user-name>
Code that I have tried so far:
const mapRoles = yaml.stringify([
    {
        rolearn: 'arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/<role-name>',
        username: '<user-name>',
        groups: ['system:masters']
    }
])


const awsAuthManifest = new eks.KubernetesManifest(this, 'AwsAuthConfigMap', {
    cluster: this.cluster,
    manifest: [
        {
            apiVersion: 'v1',
            kind: 'ConfigMap',
            metadata: {
                name: 'aws-auth',
                namespace: 'kube-system'
            },
            data: {
                mapRoles
            }
        }
    ]
})

awsAuthManifest.node.addDependency(this.cluster)

Once the cluster is created, I tried:
eksctl get iamidentitymapping --cluster <cluster-name> --region us-east-1
but I received Error: getting auth ConfigMap: Unauthorized
